# Magento 2.x Layered Navigation in Advance Search Result

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, layered-navigation, advanced-search

How can I add **Layered Navigation in Advance Search** result page?

In catalog search it is displaying Layered Navigation. But as I got result from Advance Search the left sidebar disappeared.

I want Layered Navigation in this left sidebar.

I am using Magento 2.0.7 Enterprise edition.